# Do I have to use fit() again after training in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using `LinearRegression()`. Below you can see what I have already done to predict new features:

```
    lm = LinearRegression()
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.8, random_state=say)
    lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
    lm.predict(X_test)
    scr = lm.score(X_test, y_test)
    lm.fit(X, y)
    pred = lm.predict(X_real)
```

Do I really need the line `lm.fit(X, y)` or can I just go without using it? Also, If I don't need to calculate accuracy, do you think the following approach is better instead using training and testing? (In case I don't want to test):

```
    lm.fit(X, y)
    pred = lm.predict(X_real)
```

Even I am getting 0.997 accuraccy, the predicted value is not close or shifted. Are there ways to make prediction more accurate?

Comment: To know the future...

Comment: Yes but do i need fit(X,y) even after i trained the classifier with X_train and y_train?

Comment: Questions to ponder: Why use train_test_split if you don't want to test or calculate accuracy? Why use a test_size that's 80% of the data and only train on 20%? Why do you think you need to fit it twice (re-fit)?

Comment: Well just because i don't know exact answers i am asking :) Maybe you can tell me why? What i tought is, assume i am working with very old currency data. The movement of 10 years ago is different than last 3 years. So that's why i prefered to train huge data. If you were me, what would be your approach?

Comment: This question is poorly worded, Generally fit method for all algo's will compute the math like SD, the transform method will transform the data with the computed value while "fit_transform" does the both

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to fit multiple times for predicting a value by given features since your algorithm already learned your train set. Check the codes below.

```
# Split your data into train and test sets    
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.8, random_state=0)

# Teach your data to your algorithm with train set
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Now it can predict
y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)

# Use test set to see how accurate it predicts
lr_score = lr.score(y_pred, y_test)
```

Comment: Ok but if i fit again with fit(X,y) i get different results. Do you also know how to imporve the results Yasin? I mean the prediction accuracy is about 0.997 but the predicted results are a bit higher. Are there ways to improve results using intercept or coef or mse etc?

Comment: @Khun The reason why you get different results is that you change the data which your algorithm learns when you fit another X and y. Other than that, your accuracy seems very high actually. I'm not sure how to improve the results.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting almost 100% accuracy score  is [a data leakage](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/), caused by the following line of code:

```
lm.fit(X, y)
```

in the line above you gave your model ALL the data and then you are testing prediction using the subset of data that your model has already seen.

This causes very high accuracy score for the *already seen* data, but usually it performs badly on the *unseen data*.

> When do you want / need to fit your model **multiple** times?

If you are getting a new training data and want to improve your model by training it against a new portion of data, then you may want to choose [one of regression algorithm, supporting incremental-learning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning).

In this case you will use [model.partial_fit()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.partial_fit) method instead of `model.fit()`...